# How I can draw a border in a region using delphi?

Tags: delphi

I'm using this code

```
procedure DrawPolygonRegion(wnd : HWND; rect : TRect; NumPoints : Integer; DoStarShape : Boolean);
const
  RadConvert = PI/180;
  Degrees    = 360;
  MaxLines   = 100;
var
  x, y,
  xCenter,
  yCenter,
  radius,
  pts,
  I       : Integer;
  angle,
  rotation: Extended;
  arPts   : Array[0..MaxLines] of TPoint;
  rgn  : HRGN;
begin

  xCenter := (rect.Right - rect.Left) div 2;
  yCenter := (rect.Bottom - rect.Top) div 2;
  if DoStarShape then
    begin
      rotation := Degrees/(2*NumPoints);
      pts := 2 * NumPoints;
    end
  else
    begin
      rotation := Degrees/NumPoints;             //get number of degrees to turn per point
      pts := NumPoints
    end;
  radius := yCenter;

  {This loop defines the Cartesian points of the shape. Again,
   I've added 90 degrees to the rotation angle so the shapes will
   stand up rather than lie on their sides. Thanks again to Terry Smithwick and
   David Ullrich for their trig help on CompuServe.}
  for I := 0 to pts - 1 do begin
    if DoStarShape then
      if (I mod 2) = 0 then //which means that
        radius := Round(radius/2)
      else
        radius := yCenter;

    angle := ((I * rotation) + 90) * RadConvert;
    x := xCenter + Round(cos(angle) * radius);
    y := yCenter - Round(sin(angle) * radius);
    arPts[I].X := x;
    arPts[I].Y := y;
  end;

  rgn := CreatePolygonRgn(arPts, pts, WINDING);
  SetWindowRgn(wnd, rgn, TRUE);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DrawPolygonRegion(Handle, BoundsRect, 5, True)
end;
```

to set the shape of form in this way

[image]

Now I need draw a color border in the shape, but I can't figure out how make this task. the result which I looking for is something like this.

[image]

Any ideas how accomplish this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are going to continue using a region, then call the Win32 API `FrameRgn()` function in the Form's `OnPaint` event, eg:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
  private
    Rgn: HRGN;
  protected
    procedure CreateWindowHandle(const Params: TCreateParams); override;
  end;

function CreateMyPolygonRegion(rect : TRect; NumPoints : Integer; DoStarShape : Boolean): HRGN; 
const 
  RadConvert = PI/180; 
  Degrees    = 360; 
  MaxLines   = 100; 
var 
  x, y, 
  xCenter, 
  yCenter, 
  radius, 
  pts, 
  I       : Integer; 
  angle, 
  rotation: Extended; 
  arPts   : Array[0..MaxLines] of TPoint; 
begin 
  xCenter := (rect.Right - rect.Left) div 2; 
  yCenter := (rect.Bottom - rect.Top) div 2; 
  if DoStarShape then 
    begin 
      rotation := Degrees/(2*NumPoints); 
      pts := 2 * NumPoints; 
    end 
  else 
    begin 
      rotation := Degrees/NumPoints;             //get number of degrees to turn per point 
      pts := NumPoints 
    end; 
  radius := yCenter; 

  {This loop defines the Cartesian points of the shape. Again, 
   I've added 90 degrees to the rotation angle so the shapes will 
   stand up rather than lie on their sides. Thanks again to Terry Smithwick and 
   David Ullrich for their trig help on CompuServe.} 
  for I := 0 to pts - 1 do begin 
    if DoStarShape then 
      if (I mod 2) = 0 then //which means that 
        radius := Round(radius/2) 
      else 
        radius := yCenter; 

    angle := ((I * rotation) + 90) * RadConvert; 
    x := xCenter + Round(cos(angle) * radius); 
    y := yCenter - Round(sin(angle) * radius); 
    arPts[I].X := x; 
    arPts[I].Y := y; 
  end; 

  Result := CreatePolygonRgn(arPts, pts, WINDING); 
end; 

procedure TForm1.CreateWindowHandle(const Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Rgn := CreateMyPolygonRegion(BoundsRect, 5, True);
  SetWindowRgn(Handle, Rgn, TRUE);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
  FrameRgn(Canvas.Handle, Rgn, Canvas.Brush.Handle, 2, 2);
end;
```

However, on Windows 2000 and later, it is better and more efficient on OS resources to not use window regions anymore.  `TForm` has had `Transparent` and `TransparentColor` properties available since Delphi 6, you should use them instead.  Set the `Transparent` property to `True`, set the `TransparentColor` property to a unique color that does not appear anywhere else in your Form (`clFuchsia` is commonly used), draw your desired shape and bordering onto a `TBitmap` that is the same `Width` and `Height` as the Form and has its background filled with the Form's `TranparentColor`, and then you can draw the `TBitmap` onto the Form's `Canvas` in the `OnPaint` event (or alternatively put the `TBitmap` onto a client-align `TImage` so you don't have to draw the Form manually).  Whenever Windows composites your Form's window for display, it will automatically omit the final pixels that use the `TransparentColor`.  The end result is the same - a shaped window - but Windows will be able to manage the transparency, hit testing, overlaying/blending with other windows, etc much more efficiently.